# how do I config a Foscam FI9821W IP camera on Firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, video, camera, zoneminder

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox. I've got a Foscam FI9821W IP camera and I'm trying to get live video on Firefox. Then I want to add to zoneminder. I opened the IPCam Client page and downloaded and installed the plugin as prompted, hit "login" and there was the next page of the IPCam Client. No live video, like the Foscam users manual said. Is there something wrong with the plugin? I've been reading online that Foscam doesn't really support Linux, like they claim. I managed to add the camera to zoneminder, but the IP address is red and not orange like it should be. Which means it's not working. Has anyone had experience with Foscam HD cameras? Can someone help me?

Comment: Foscam supports one camera on Linux just fine.  It only lacks the multiple camera support you get from IE.  What plugin are you using?  Just point firefox to the camera's IP and you should get the login page, use the "server push" login.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Foscam Client with Wine. With that you can configure the cam.
Then use vlc to view the video

rtsp://[username]:[password]@[IP-of-the-cam]:443/videoMain

with the client tool you can control the position and vlc is your view.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP asks about Firefox, not VLC

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the cam with zoneminder but I do not recommend, it's a hell of a job to find out the settings and it will not always connect.

Since the latest version of firefox server push doesn't work anymore.

To see a streaming video you have to use Google Chrome browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidFoerster This looks like an attempt to answer the question to me, although it could use some clarification. Joha: Could you [edit] your answer to expand on how to use Google Chrome to stream the video?

Answer (score 0):

I have found Zoneminder to be a power hog so I don't use it. I have not had any luck using VLC. Foscam requires a plugin which sometimes works with Wine+Firefox+myfoscam.com. I have never been able to use myfoscam.com in Ubuntu+Firefox.

I have had success using Ubuntu+Chrome+MyIpCam-apt from the Chrome store. My Netgear server forwards port 88 to the camera which has a static ip. By knowing my external ip address I am able to view the camera on the web.